# Configure Node HTTP server timeout when using ASP.NET Core NodeServices

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-2.2

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to configure the Node HTTP server timeout from ASP.NET Core's NodeServices APIs? Or in any other way from within the invoked Node module?

---

We're using ASP.NET Core's [NodeServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices) APIs to invoke JavaScript modules that generate PDFs using the [node-html-pdf](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf) library.

Due to the content of the PDFs, processing time is exceeding two minutes, [which is the default timeout for the Node HTTP server](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout) which is being created as part of the ASP.NET Core NodeServices run time.

When this timeout is reached, the Node HTTP server closes the connection to the calling service (even though process execution still continues), meaning it's impossible to get the complete PDF back from the Node module.

From what I can see, it's not possible to configure this timeout currently.

1. Is it possible to configure this timeout from the NodeServices APIs?
2. Is it possible to configure this timeout from within the Node module being invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the answer to my question is no, it's not possible.

GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8447).